# Trying to loop method infinitely

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I am just curious why can't I infinitely loop my method, when i try this with "while(true)" then it works, but if i do that with my Object "Counter" which runs method "function()" infinitely then it works only to 6200, sometimes it changes maximal value to ~6100 or ~6300, does anybody know why it works this way and maybe how ?

```
public class Infinity {

  public static void main(String[] argv)
  {
    //Counter count = new Counter((short)0,(short)6180,(short)1);
    //count.startCounter(true);


    int a = 1;
    while (true) { 
      a = a + 1;
      System.out.println("Value: " + a);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Main class

```
public class Counter 
{
  private short max;
  private short number;
  private short multiplicator;

  public Counter(short n,short m,short mp)
  {
    System.out.println("Implementing given numbers...");
    this.number=n;
    this.max=m;
    this.multiplicator=mp;
    System.out.println("");
  }

  public void startCounter(boolean b)
  {
    if (b == true) 
    {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Starting counting from " + this.number + " to " + this.max);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    this.function();
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Your Counter was set to false, abborting Start...");
    } 
  }

  public void function()
  {
    if (this.number < this.max) 
    {
      this.number = (short)(this.number + this.multiplicator);
      System.out.println("Number: " + this.number);
      this.function();
    } 
    else {
      System.out.println("Ending of Number");
    } 
  }
}
```

This is my additional Counter class

Comment: Are you getting a `StackOverflow` error?

Comment: @EliSadoff you mean Stackoverflow?

Comment: When i set my max number for example to 9000, then i get many lines of "at Counter.function(Counter.java:36)"

Comment: @AndrewL. That's also the [error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) you get when you use recursion too much. It overflows your stack.

Comment: I know, it's a StackOverflowError, StackOverflow is the site name @EliSadoff just a branding thing

Comment: Oh haha. I thought you meant the error didn't exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code you posted isn't a loop, it's a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function call.

It might be helpful to think of `Counter.function()` as a black box. When it's called, program execution enters the black box and doesn't return outside it until the function is done (i.e. when it returns).

So the first time you call `function()`, you're entering one black box. Then you call `function()` again *from within itself*, entering a new black box. But here's the catch - you haven't exited the first black box yet! So you'll end up with something like this:

```
Executing function()
    Executing function()
        Executing function()
            ...etc...
        return;
    return;
return;
```

The problem is that for each black box entered, Java needs to allocate memory [on the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation), and that memory can't be released until the function (the black box) is done executing. As a consequence, you'll eventually run out of memory.

What you should do instead is, as you suggest in your question, use a loop:

```
public bool function() {
    if (this.number < this.max) {
        this.number = (short)(this.number + this.multiplicator);
        System.out.println("Number: " + this.number);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ending of Number");
    }

    return (this.number < this.max);
}
```

And to call it you can use something like this:

```
while( function() )
    ;
```

or this:

```
while(true){
    if( !function() )
        break;
}
```

This allows one function call to be finished before the next one is begun. Or, to continue the analogy of black boxes, it will look more like this:

```
Executing function()
return;
Executing function()
return;
Executing function()
return;
...etc...
```

Comment: Wow, this was really helpfull, now i finally understand how it works!, really thank you for that :)

Comment: Can i somehow make it calculating slower ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant infinitely run your loop, because Java saves the Activation Records (AR) of the Dinamically Enclosing Scope (DES) in the Stack, but the Stack doesnt have infinitely space.

So, in order, to avoid to use all the memory space you have, Java throws a StackOverflow error.

Comment: Thanks!, I didn't know that, now I'm going to read about (AR) and (DES) in Internet, really thank you ! :)